# PolymerJS: Iron-Ajax - How to Bind Token to Headers Property?

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I have a polymer-element and I want to apply a token as headers attribute.

When I push the button an XMLHttpReqeust is send. The responsible `iron-ajax` element has a `headers` property with a string. I would like to change the string, and apply a different attribute.

I've been told that normal `compound bindings` does not work and I should try `computed bindings` or just `computed properties`.

But the problem seems to be the question, how to `bind` these `computed properties` or `computed bindings` to the `iron-ajax` element?

Whenever I use curly braces, nothing gets evaluated. And if I leave them out, only the remaining string gets parsed.

Here is my element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="demo-element">
    <template>
        <button on-click="sendXMLHttpRequest">sendXMLHttpRequest</button>

        <div>
            Computed Binding HeadersProperty: 
            <span>{{computeHeadersProperty(csrfToken)}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            Computed Property HeadersProperty: 
            <span>{{headersProperty}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            Computed Binding HeadersToken: 
            <span>{{computeHeadersToken(csrfToken)}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            Computed Property HeadersToken: 
            <span>{{headersToken}}</span>
        </div>

        <iron-ajax
             id="ajax"
             method="POST"
             url=""
             handle-as="json"
             headers='{"X-CSRF-Token": "csrfToken"}'
             ></iron-ajax>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'demo-element',

            properties: {
                csrfToken: {
                    type: String,
                    value: 'aBcDeF'
                },
                headersProperty: {
                    type: String,
                    computed: 'computeHeadersProperty(csrfToken)'
                },
                headersToken: {
                    type: String,
                    computed: 'computeHeadersToken(csrfToken)'
                }

            },

            sendXMLHttpRequest: function () {
                // ajax call
                this.$.ajax.body = this.headersProperty;
                this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
            },

            computeHeadersProperty: function (csrfToken) {
                return '{"X-CSRF-Token":\"' + csrfToken + '\"}';
            },

            computeHeadersToken: function (csrfToken) {
                return csrfToken;
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

As you can see I have created computed bindings and properties for the complete `headers` property and also just for the token I want to pass in.

But the iron-ajax element does not evaluate anything, when I use curly braces.

Here is what I have tried in the `iron-ajax` element so far:

1. headers='{"X-CSRF-Token": "{{csrfToken}}"}' // doesn't evaluate
2. headers='{"X-CSRF-Token": "{{headersToken}}"}' // doesn't evaluate
3. headers="{{headersProperty}}" // doesn't evaluate
4. headers="{{computeHeadersProperty(csrfToken)}}" // doesn't evaluate
5. headers='{"X-CSRF-Token": "{{computeHeadersToken(csrfToken)}}"}' // doesn't evaluate
6. headers='{"X-CSRF-Token": "headersToken"}' // evalutes to `{"X-CSRF-Token": "headersToken"}`
7. headers='computeHeadersProperty(csrfToken)' // doesn't evaluate

So, how do I have to bind an attribute to the `headers` property of the `iron-ajax` element?

---

### EDIT

---

Some users have have provided a "working solution", which is unfortunately not working, because the `headers` seem to be set, but it is not included in the `headers request`. Proof:

[image: Headers Binding Not Working]

Compare this to the case when we use a Random String:

[image: Headers String Working]

Here the `x-csrf-token` is properly set.

Because it is not possible to check the request in the provided JSBIN I included a git repository here with the example code: https://github.com/LoveAndHappiness/polymer-iron-ajax-issue-159

I had to include dependencies instead of the polygit resources, because polygit throws errors when working with `iron-ajax`.

---

#### How to reproduce the error?

1. git clone https://github.com/LoveAndHappiness/polymer-iron-ajax-issue-159.git
2. Open DevTools and Hit the Request Button. You will see that no headers are set.
   Change in the `iron-ajax` element the headers property on line 50 from

`headers='{{computeHeadersProperty(csrfToken)}}'`

to

`headers='{"X-CSRF-Token":"ARandomString"}'`

3. Hit the Request Button again and check in Dev-Tools to see that the token is now accurately set in the headers request.

#### What I think the error boils down to

Judging by the Output of the Console, the errors seems to be, that the `headings` property in the `iron-ajax` element expects an `Object`, but the evaluation from the databinding returns a `string`.

I hope somebody can at least reproduce the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `headersProperty` wants to be an `Object` and not a `String`.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/rasoqexese/edit?html,output

Many thanks to [Peter Burns](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/issues/159)

Comment: That worked for me. It might also be worth to note that I had to do
`X-CSRFToken` as the key to pass to my headers.

Answer (score 1):

The last action on this topic is about half a year ago. I tried the same thing: Adding a token to the header of the iron-ajax request. I tried everything the original poster tried and I tried everything shown in the answers. I searched the net for about three weeks, sometimes several hours each evening. I didn't find a solution. Nothing worked. The properties doesn't evaluate and/or they are not added to the header of the request.

My answer: It looks like it is **not possible** to add computed properties to the headers of an iron-ajax request **yet**. Keep in mind that **Polymer is a very new framework** and a lot of things need to be improved over the next releases.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding). This will work for you:

```
    <iron-ajax
         id="ajax"
         method="POST"
         url=""
         handle-as="json"
         headers$='{"X-CSRF-Token": "{{csrfToken}}"}'
         ></iron-ajax>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put `notify:true` on your `csrfToken` property.

Comment: I tried it with `notify: true` with no difference. Could you maybe expand on your suggestion?

Comment: I was just trying to figure out why the headers attribute of the ajax element wasn't getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is at least a working [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/befebus/edit?html,console,output) version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer Bin</title>
    <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
    <!-- Third-party imports -->
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" rel="import">
    <!-- Styling -->
    <style>
    </style>
    <dom-module id="demo-element">
      <template>
          <button on-click="sendXMLHttpRequest">sendXMLHttpRequest</button>
          <iron-ajax
               id="ajax"
               method="POST"
               url=""
               handle-as="json"
               headers="{{computeHeadersProperty(csrfToken)}}"
               >
          </iron-ajax>
      </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'demo-element',

            properties: {
                csrfToken: {
                    type: String,
                    value: 'aBcDeF'
                },
                headersProperty: {
                    type: String,
                    computed: 'computeHeadersProperty(csrfToken)'
                },
                headersToken: {
                    type: String,
                    computed: 'computeHeadersToken(csrfToken)'
                }
            },

            sendXMLHttpRequest: function () {
                // ajax call
                console.log("Headers in AJAX: " + this.$.ajax.headers);
                //this.$.ajax.body = this.headersProperty;
                //this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
            },

            computeHeadersProperty: function (csrfToken) {
                return {"X-CSRF-Token": ' + csrfToken };
            }
        });
    </script>  
  </head>
  <body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <demo-element></demo-element>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Pascal, I updated my post with an Edit, because your solution did not work yet.