# Headers not being sent by iron-ajax

Tags: polymer

I'm new to Polymer (I'm trying to learn how to also use it with Angular 2 as well concurrently) and after looking through the docs, it looks like this

```
<iron-ajax url="https://httpbin.org/get" last-response="{{data}}" handle-as="json"
       headers="{'Authorization': 'pew'}" auto>
```

but the headers didn't contain the Authorization header

```
"headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Origin": "http://localhost:3000", 
    "Referer": "http://localhost:3000/", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
}
```

so after some Googling, I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34340468/2038087) and tried to do what was explained and my `iron-ajax` changed to

```
<iron-ajax url="https://httpbin.org/get" last-response="{{data}}" handle-as="json"
       headers="'{{getHeadersURL()}}'" auto>
```

with `getHeadersURL()` looking like

```
var headers = {'Authorization': 'pew'};

function getHeadersURL() {
    return headers;
}
```

However, even after sending this, the headers are still the same as above. Is there something I'm not understanding or something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your headers are not properly formatted as JSON because of the single-quotes. The [JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/) requires strings to be enclosed in double-quotes. If you try parsing what you have now, you'll see an error:

```js
try {
  // single-quotes == invalid JSON
  JSON.parse("{'Authorization': 'pew'}");
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
```

Rewriting your examples to use double-quoted strings resolves the issue.

*Binding headers inline:*

```
<iron-ajax headers='{"Authorization": "pew"}'>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.6.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax url="https://httpbin.org/get"
                 last-response="{{data}}"
                 on-response="_onResponse"
                 headers='{"Authorization": "pew"}'
                 auto>
      </iron-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          _onResponse: function(e) {
            console.log('response', e.detail.response);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zBmYYd?editors=1002)

*Binding headers returned from a function:*

```
<iron-ajax headers="{{getHeaders()}}">

// script
Polymer({
  ...
  getHeaders: function() {
    return {"Authorization": "pew"};
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.6.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax url="https://httpbin.org/get"
                 last-response="{{data}}"
                 on-response="_onResponse"
                 headers="{{getHeaders()}}"
                 auto>
      </iron-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          _onResponse: function(e) {
            console.log('response', e.detail.response);
          },
          getHeaders: function() {
            return {"Authorization": "pew"};
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/dXgyyj?editors=1002)

Comment: OK, so I tried running it the way you showed me [here](http://jsbin.com/duzapajode/edit?html,css,js,console,output) and it worked , but when I ran it locally, I still had the same problem. However, locally, I use Bower components for Polymer, and iron-ajax is on version 1.4.3 while PolyGit uses a later version (not sure which one). I think that's the reason why.

Comment: Would you recommend using PolyGit or should I still continue using the bower components?

Comment: PolyGit is not for production, so stick with Bower in your code. `1.4.3` *is* the latest version of `iron-ajax`, so there is no later version.